# Atom: Error running Hydrogen, python.exe can't be found

Tags: python, anaconda

I've recently run a complete reinstallation of `Anaconda`, as well as `Atom` with `Script` and `Hydrogen`. Before the reinstallation everything ran fine. Now, 
when trying to execute a Python script line using `Ctrl+Enter` I'm getting the following error:

`'C:\Users\vestland\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

[image: error]

And that's no wonder, because there ***is no*** `python.exe` in that folder. It's in `'C:\Users\vestland\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\SCRIPT\python.exe'`. How can I change that reference within Atom?

I've tried adding `'C:\Users\vestland\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\SCRIPT\python.exe'` to `PATH` but to no avail.

I've also tried editing the Hydrogen `kernel.json` file as per the suggestion [here](https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen/issues/1432) to:

```
{
 "display_name": "MyPython3",
 "argv": [
  "C:\\Users\\vestland\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\scripts\\python.exe",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "language": "python"
}
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

**Edit:**

Running Python using `ctrl+shift+b` works just fine! But that's a command for the `Script` package and not `Hydrogen`.

Comment: Have you tried launching Atom from the command line? This fixes Jupyter-related Hydrogen issues for me.

Comment: @ I have. I ran `atom ` from windows command line. Didn't help.

Comment: @CameronHyde Could you elaborate on what system you're running? Windows? Perhaps some version info on? I'm really eager to get these things up and running.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu Linux. Hydrogen certainly seems to have some environment issues, I wish I knew more than that sorry.

Comment: @CameronHyde No worries! Thank you for responding anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** ***Remove lurking kernels!***

For some unknown reason, after countless reinstallations of Python, Atom, Script, Hydrogen and various attempts of

```
python -m pip install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

... I found a rogue kernel lurking in the depths of

```
C:\Users\vestland\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\python3
```

As you can see from the screenshot, it's been there for quite some time despite my countless efforts to reset the entire system:

[image]

So I just deleted it, fired up Atom using a command prompt and `atom .`,
and now everything runs just fine using keyboard shortcuts for Hydrogen:

[image]

**The details:**

Running `C:\>jupyter kernelspec list --json` returned:

```
{
  "kernelspecs": {
    "1450be76-28c2-4c3d-a5f0-c56b3ef13d75": {
      "resource_dir": "C:\\Users\vestland\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\kernels\\1450be76-28c2-4c3d-a5f0-c56b3ef13d75",
      "spec": {
        "argv": [
          "C:\\Users\\vestland\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python.exe",
        [...]
      }
    },
    "python3": {
      "resource_dir": "C:\\Users\vestlad\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\kernels\\python3",
      "spec": {
        "argv": [
          "C:\\Users\\vestland\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python.exe",
         [...]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And that turned out to be the culprit of the problem and why I could not rid myself of the `C:\\Users\\vestland\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python.exe` error message. Somehow, Hydrogen picked up on that directory each time I tried to do something with Hydrogen and Atom.

Running `jupyter kernelspec list` showed me the locations of these kernels:

```
Available kernels:
  1450be76-28c2-4c3d-a5f0-c56b3ef13d75    C:\Users\vestland\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\1450be76-28c2-4c3d-a5f0-c56b3ef13d75
  python3                                 C:\Users\vestland\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\python3
```

A simple deletion of the former kernel solved all problems. For now...

Answer (score 3):

If you python location is `C:\Users\vestland\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\SCRIPT\python.exe` the `kernel.json` file has an additional `s` in `scripts`, the correct version would be:

```
{
 "display_name": "MyPython3",
 "argv": [
  "C:\\Users\\vestland\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-3\\SCRIPT\\python.exe",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "language": "python"
}
```

But I would suggest that `kernel.json` uses the python default from the `PATH` only you are not planning to use any virtual environment.

```
{
 "display_name": "MyPython3",
 "argv": [
  "python.exe",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "language": "python"
}
```

If that doesn't work, check if the system kernel folder is used instead, you can find it in `%PROGRAMDATA%\jupyter\kernels`

Comment: I finally found a working solution myself. However, as a thank you for your extensive efforts, the bounty is yours. Your initial answer was actually what lead me to a solution when I sought to learn more about `python -m pip install ipykernel` and `python -m ipykernel install --user`.

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried adding 'C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\SCRIPT\python.exe' to PATH but to no avail.

Try adding 'C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\SCRIPT\' to PATH instead and restart Atom. (In other words add the folder containing the exe instead of the path\filename.)

Comment: Thank you for yout suggestion! I've tried that, and it did not work.